# How to add user to multiple groups in AD using LDAP protocol?

Tags: kotlin, active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Using this code I can add user to group

```
val addUser: Modification = Modification(ModificationType.ADD, "member", userDn)
val ldapResult = ldapConnectionPool.modify(groupDn, addUser)
```

Now I want to add user to multiple groups.

I underdstand that I can use loop but it will require multiple ldap requests. Is there way to do it using single ldap request ?